# How to set dynamic default value for an entity class field by using hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria, dynamic-mapping

I need to dynamically allocate value at creation time for an entity by fetching value from related table. Consider the below scenario where I have two classes - Student & Batch.

While inserting a new record in Student table at the time of creation, I need to set the field 'allocatedBatch' in Student table by fetching Batch for which 'Active' field  is **true** from Batch table.(considering the fact that only one batch can be active at the given time)

And this has to be done dynamically. Please suggest me some best usage of hibernate to handle this.

*Note - As this has to be done without using the respective service and repository class, looking for hibernate usage*

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(Strategy = GeneratedType.Identity)
private Integer id;

private String name;

private Date DOB;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "Student_Batch", nullable=false)
private Batch allocatedBatch;

.....Getter and setter methods....
}
```

**Batch.java**

```
public class Batch {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(Strategy = GeneratedType.Identity)
private Integer id;

private String name;

private Date startDate;

 @ColumnDefault("false")
private boolean Active;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "allocatedBatch", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Set<Student> students;

.....Getter and setter methods....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your circumstances, but this sounds like you may need to rethink your design. However, I think using Event listener or Interceptor might do the trick. (If I understand this correctly)

Check out `@PrePersist` annotation. [JPA Callback](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-jpa-callbacks)

Comment: Thanks @raminr . I edited my description now for better understanding. I tried PrePersist but I am facing challenges like autowiring respective service class in my entity class(here Student.java)

Comment: Why is your OneToMany attribute not a collection? The way you have it, the relationship is really OneToOne.

Comment: I think you need to remember the lifecycle of a JPA entity: Transient, Managed, Detached, Removed. It sounds like you wish to have the Batch attribute to be populated on Student when you instantiate a new object. That's not going to magically happen because the Student entity is in Transient state at that time and Hibernate doesn't know anything about it. If you want this to happen at save time, then you can do that with @PrePersist.

Comment: Thanks @raminr. I tried with PrePersist and it seems to be close with my requirement.